# How to set encoding pageContext.getOut().write(message)?

Tags: java, encoding, pagecontext

what is default encoding of 
`pageContext.getOut().write(message`) and how to set the other encoding if I need?

Answer (score 0):

The default encoding relate to your Browser, you can set the encoding by using:

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
```